# .Net Core / Angular 6 - Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, angular6, asp.net-core-webapi

I am wondering why I am getting "origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error while trying to send data from frontend to backend. On the frontend side I am using angular 6, and on the backend side I am using Asp.Net Core 2.1 (web api). I set everything as they said in this Microsoft article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1

But it's still not working. I don't know is it some problem with angular app setup or I am just doing something wrong here.

back-end works on: https://localhost:5001/

front-end works on: https://localhost:4200/

.net core app - startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options => options
        .AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", p =>
            p.WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .AllowAnyHeader()));

    services.AddResponseCaching();

    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

    app.UseResponseCaching();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

I also tried to use [EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")] attribute at controller which is giving me this error, but still not working. I am not sure is it worth to write, but all my HttpGet method working without any issue. So this is not working correctly only for HttpPost. What the strangest thing is that yesterday everything worked without any issue, no changes was made in cors configuration etc and today can't connect front-end with back-end side.

PS. I also wrote this in startup.cs under services.AddMvc() but it also didn't help:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => {
    options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory(PolicyName));
});
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do both your applications use https?

Comment: @YankovViacheslav yes, both apps use https

Comment: I have the same issue.  I can even see my request including the header, but somehow .NET side is not seeing it come across.

Answer (score 0):

try my useCors

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        .......



        app.UseCors(cfg => { cfg.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().WithExposedHeaders("X-Metadata"); });
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: This also didn't fix it, but thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the logs and it was the problem in ef core. Yesterday I've created EF Migrations in the project and when it generates database it creates two not needed unique keys on properties. Error in log:

```
SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: Expense.FromUserId'.
```

I removed this two lines in OnModelCreating method in DbContext (this was creating additional unique constraint) and now everything works ok:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Expense>().HasOne(x => x.FromUser).WithOne();
modelBuilder.Entity<Expense>().HasOne(x => x.ToUser).WithOne();
```

It's really strange that I was getting "Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error inside the browser. Can anyone explain that?